# MySQL optimization - Delete on certain count

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm building a chat for a turn-based game (using PHP and MySQL) where I only want to save the 30 most recent messages in the MySQL database.

Currently, I'm doing 3 queries to delete the oldest message when the count exceeds 30:

1. Insert the new chat message as a new row:

   > INSERT INTO chatMessages (userId,matchId,message,timestamp) VALUES (".$params["userId"].",".$params["matchId"].",'".$params["message"]."',NOW())
2. Check if there are too many messages in the database, and get the oldest one's Id.

   > SELECT COUNT(id) AS count, id AS oldestId FROM chatMessages WHERE matchId = ".$params["matchId"]." ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
3. Remove the oldest message

   > DELETE FROM chatMessages WHERE id = ".$oldestId

Is there any way to do this in 2, or even 1 single query? We have quite a lot of traffic on our servers, so performance is key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the 2nd and 3rd query to one:

```
delete from chatMessages 
where id not in (select id from chatMessages 
                 order by id desc 
                 limit 30)
```

You could put that in an insert trigger. That way oldest records would get deleted automatically after an insert.

Comment: Will that improve performance though? 3 queries will still have to be made, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: The query above will delete **all** records that are too old in one query. The 2 queries you used only delete one record. And it is faster to execute one query (with a subquery maybe) instead of 2 seperate queries.

Comment: It would be faster if you don't delete the records all the time. You could use a scheduled trigger if you really have to delete them sometimes. Why not change your select query to get the 30 most recent entries? You know that tables can easily store thousands or millions of records.